# How to make entire DOM draggable & resizable via jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to "activate" an entire DOM to be draggable and resizable using jQuery UI? I then want to save the user's new positions in HTML5's data attribute to recreate the page later.

Imagine this same page you're looking at to be "activated" when you just hover, click, drag, and resize all the visible elements around (snapping would be super nice!). Any advice or idea on this?

Comment: You want to do what? Customize webpages?

Comment: Do you mean every element on the page or just the `<html>` tag?

Comment: @megaperlz, ya I'm thinking customizable web pages. So probably all visible elements would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Thr4wn said, if you give each element that should move a class, then you can give each member of that class a function that updates its location when it changes.  I suggest using [960.gs](http://960.gs/) as a grid to remember locations.

This way you can each objects classes as html5 data.

Answer (score 3):

Making literally every div/span as drag and droppable is non-sensable. What we has humans easily observe as a atomic "unit" (like the 'javascript' tag box) is not so obvious internally in the HTML structure. So you may have to do some thinking and decide what you want included in "everything" that becomes Drag and droppable. And at that point, you can just name all those elements with a "dd" class and use that.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, just do this :

`$('*').draggable();`

Not really sure why you would want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to you could use the `$("*")` selector. but I would not suggest it...